# How to replace a Bitmap background to a certain color

Tags: java, android, background, bitmap, android-canvas

I have a PNG image (R.drawable.circle) that has a transparent background. I need to draw it in the canvas that is why I convert it into Bitmap. But I want the transparent background to be Color.WHITE. How do I do that? Is it possible?

```
private void drawer(Canvas canvas) {
      Bitmap animal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.circle);
      canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(animal,100,100, false), 0, 0, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
private void drawer(Canvas canvas) {

        Bitmap bitmapOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle);
        Bitmap bitmapNew = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOriginal.getWidth(), bitmapOriginal.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmapNew.eraseColor(Color.WHITE); // color that You want to set

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapNew, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOriginal, 0, 0, null);

    }
```

Comment: sorry i dont have enough reputation :(

Comment: Allocating a separate Bitmap just to draw a solid coloured rectangle is pretty inefficient.

Comment: just recycle a bitmap after creating new one.

Answer (score 0):

Fill the canvas with your desired background color before drawing the bitmap, e.g.

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```

As an aside, you shouldn't need to write low-level drawing code like that just to render a bitmap resouce on a background color. You can simply use an ImageView with src and background.